# Aharanov–Bohm effect: what happens if I turn off the magnetic field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, aharonov-bohm

I've recently been trying to really understand what's going on in the Aharanov–Bohm effect, and I've crystallized my questions into the following variant of the typical Aharanov–Bohm setup.

Begin with the typical Aharanov–Bohm setup. Consider a charge-$q$ particle moving around in an annular region. If we inject a flux $\Phi$ into the region and the particle makes a single rotation around the region, it picks up a relative phase $e^{2\pi i \Phi/\Phi_0}$, where $\Phi_0 = h/q$ is the flux quantum. This relative phase can be experimentally detected.

Now consider the following variant: First, move the particle an angle $0 < \theta < 2\pi$ around the annulus. Then, holding the particle as stationary as possible consistent with the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, slowly turn off the magnetic field in the center of the region. Then continue to rotate the particle the remaining angle $2\pi - \theta$ to its starting point. What is the relative phase in this case?

This process has three stages: (1) the initial rotation of angle $\theta$, (2) turning the magnetic field off, and (3) the final rotation of $2\pi - \theta$. I expect step (2) will result in changes to the phase, because I can convince myself of different answers to the question if I consider just parts (1) and (3) in different gauges:

- First, consider the conventional gauge for Aharanov–Bohm where $A(r,\varphi,z) = \frac{\Phi}{2\pi r} \hat{\varphi}$  in the annular region when the flux is on. I pick up a relative phase $e^{\theta i \Phi/\Phi_0}$ during (1). When the magnetic field is off, $A\equiv 0$ and I pick up no additional phase during (3). Thus, the total phase picked up during (1) and (3) is $e^{\theta i \Phi/\Phi_0}$.
- Second, choose a gauge in which $A \equiv 0$ along the arc of angle $\theta$ while the magnetic field is turned on and $A\equiv 0$ everywhere after the field is turned off. This is possible because integrals along $A$ are path-independent in a simply connected domain containing the arc of angle $\theta$ during part (1). In this gauge, the phase picked up during steps (1) and (3) is trivial $=1$.

Based on these two contradictory answers, I expect that something happens during (2) which corrects for the gauge-dependent answers I get by just treating (1) and (3). This leads me to ask: *What relative phase does a charged particle pick up in an Aharanov–Bohm experiment where the magnetic field is turned off mid-experiment (i.e., all three steps (1), (2), and (3))?*

Comment: A nice question! The problem is that the line integral of the 3-potential through space isn’t actually gauge invariant. You should instead perform the line integral of the 4-potential through spacetime. (In the usual setup, we choose the scalar potential to be zero, so the time part doesn’t contribute.) I’m not sure what phase you’ll get, but I’d bet it’s your first option.

Comment: You seem to suggest the charged particle has some property called phase and one can move the particle along prescribed trajectory. I thought it is the psi function that has phase, not particle, and this phase is gauge-dependent. And I worry one can't really manipulate the particle in the suggested way in QT. Also, when the magnetic flux is changing, there is induced electric field outside, which may influence the psi function phase as well.

Comment: what is the $\psi$ that makes $\vec A \rightarrow \vec A + \nabla \psi=0$?

Comment: @JánLalinský I believe it is consistent with QT to move a particle along a specified trajectory up to some small uncertainty in position and momentum ensured by the Heisenberg relation, but I might totally be wrong about this. If I am correct, the particle would have to be steered by a force which might have its own A–B effect to worry about, possibly polluting my thought experiment. Certainly the phase is a property of the wave function at each point, but I imagine that we could start the particle out in some small region with a constant phase and ask how the phase is different at the end

Comment: @JEB in any *simply connected region* in which $\vec A$ is curl-free, $\psi(x)=-\int_{P_x} \vec{A}\cdot d\vec{\ell}$, where the contour integral is taken along a path from a fixed base point to $x_0$ to the point $x$, will do the job